# Java 8 Elegant way to handle multiple method call in sequence along with failure

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to call all steps one after another and update the same instance based on the outcome of each steps. And if there is an issue with any specific step, i need to set failStep field and stop executing the following step. I need some elegant way to handle this scenario. I tried map operation, but not sure how to stop the further execution if the step is failed.

```
package abc.service;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.Optional;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.func();
    }

    public void func() {
        Abc abc = new Abc();
        abc.setId("1234");

        Abc abcd = Optional.ofNullable(abc)
                .map(step1 -> getFirstStep(abc))
                .map(step1 -> getSecondStep(abc))
                .map(step1 -> getThirdStep(abc))
                .orElse(abc);
        System.out.println("Answer: " + abcd);
    }

    private Abc getFirstStep(Abc abc) {
        abc.setStep1("STEP1");
        return abc;
    }

    private Abc getSecondStep(Abc abc) {
        abc.setStep2("STEP2");
        abc.setFailStep("STEP2");
        return abc;
    }

    private Abc getThirdStep(Abc abc) {
        abc.setStep3("STEP3");
        return abc;
    }
}

@Data
@ToString
class Abc {
    private String id;
    private String step1;
    private String step2;
    private String step3;
    private String failStep;
}
```

One simple way is to add null check inside all step method.

```
private Abc getThirdStep(Abc abc) {
    if(abc.getFailStep() == null) {
        abc.setStep3("STEP3");
    }
    return abc;
}
```

Any suggestion to handle this better and elegant way.

Comment: throw an exception and handle put the method failStep() inside.  this is a common way to do it.  usually using RxJAva.

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra Here i need to throw RuntimeException. Is that correct?

Comment: *"i need to set failStep field and **stop executing** the following step"* - do you need to interrupt only the current step, or subsequent steps?

Comment: If you just want to modify the original object Optional isn't the right tool for the task.

Comment: No. just Throw a custom Exception, runtimeException it's other kind of exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the behavior you want by returning Optional so that an empty result signals a failure to the rest of a chain of flatMaps.

```java
    public void func() {
        Abc abc = new Abc();
        abc.setId("1234");

        Abc abcd = Optional.ofNullable(abc)
                .flatMap(this::getFirstStep)
                .flatMap(this::getSecondStep)
                .flatMap(this::getThirdStep)
                .orElse(abc);
        System.out.println("Answer: " + abcd);
    }

    private static Optional<Abc> toReturn(Abc abc) {
      return abc.getFailStep() == null ? Optional.of(abc) : Optional.empty();
    }
    
    private Optional<Abc> getFirstStep(Abc abc) {
        abc.setStep1("STEP1");
        return toReturn(abc);
    }

    private Optional<Abc> getSecondStep(Abc abc) {
        abc.setStep2("STEP2");
        abc.setFailStep("STEP2");
        return toReturn(abc);
    }

    private Optional<Abc> getThirdStep(Abc abc) {
        abc.setStep3("STEP3");
        return toReturn(abc);
    }
```

However I strongly recommend against code like this. Everyone who reads it will waste five minutes figuring out how it works. If that's 50 people over time, you've wasted almost 4 hours plus all the effort of inventing this trickiness.

Just factor it into a flat function and use a series of "if" guards.

```
Abc createAbcAndApplySteps() {
  Abc abc = new Abc();
  abc.setId("1234");
  doFirstStep(abc);
  if (abc.getFailStep() != null) return abc;
  doSecondStep(abc);
  if (abc.getFailStep() != null) return abc;
  doThirdStep(abc);
  return abc;
}
```

Or better yet throw an exception at the point the error is flagged. They're in the language to make error handling clean.

```
  // Call 
  private static void fail(Abc abc, String failMsg) {
    abc.setFailStep(failMsg);
    throw AbcStepFailureException("Fail: " + failMsg);
  }
```

I guarantee you that any tech lead who knows their job will favor the third and second idioms over the first. "Elegance" is often just a fancy word for obscurity.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it the other way around, not creating Optional from abc but creating a sequence (list or whatever) from the functions. Something like this:

```java
    public void func() {
        Abc abc = new Abc();
        abc.setId("1234");

        Function<Abc, Abc> f1 = input -> getFirstStep(input);
        Function<Abc, Abc> f2 = input -> getSecondStep(input);
        Function<Abc, Abc> f3 = input -> getThirdStep(input);

        Abc abcd = doStuff(abc, List.of(f1, f2, f2));

        System.out.println("Answer: " + abcd);
    }

    public Abc doStuff(Abc input, List<Function<Abc, Abc>> functions) {
        if (functions.isEmpty()) return input; //no more functions to apply
        else {
            final var function = functions.get(0);
            final var remainingFunctions = functions.subList(1, functions.size());
            final var abc = function.apply(input);
            if (abc.getFailStep() != null) {
                //Short circuit here
                return abc;
            } else {
                //continue applying the rest of the functions
                return doStuff(abc, remainingFunctions);
            }
        }
    }
```

This will terminate after step 2. Don't use exceptions to control the program flow.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, this a wrong usage of `Optinal.map()`. that utility should be only used if the given function (ex:`getFirstStep(),getSecondStep()` ) might return null value.

But if you still need to use `Optinal` here, there are two  ways, but both have its own drawbacks.

1. Use custom `RuntimeException` and throw it from functions and catch it where you call the map method.
2. if a step failed, set that to the ABC object and return null, you can get the failure information from `abc` not from `abcd` , in this case map method will be executed 3 times, but no function will be executed after you return null.